# Differential system wirh initial condition, at the endpoint

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let's consider the following linear differential equations:

Let $A\in \mathcal{M}_{n,n}$:
$$\begin{cases}
-X'(t)=A X(t) \, \,\,\,\, t\in (0,T) \\
X(T)=X_T 
\end{cases}$$
Can we solve this system, because instead of having an initial condition in $t=0$, we have one in $t=T$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can solve ! Put $Z(t):= X(T-t).$

Then we get $Z'(t)=-X'(T-t)=AX(T-t)=AZ(t).$

This leads to the initial value problem

$Z'(t)=A Z(t) , t\in (0,T), \quad Z(0)=X_T$

Comment: Oh, so it's like we are solving it backwards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an ordinary initial value problem, only that you are interested in the solution before the initial point.

This is in the principle the same as giving an initial condition $X(0)=X_0$ and then being interested in the values of $X$ on the negative half axis.